# Computing the trace of a linear map, expressed in terms of a generating set which is not a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

Assume that $V$ is a finite-dimensional, complex vector space such that $v_1,\ldots,v_n\in V$ generate $V$, but $\dim(V)<n$. Let $\phi:V\to V$ be a linear map which I can describe in terms of the $v_i$, i.e. I know $\lambda_{ij}\in\mathbb C$ such that $\phi(v_i)=\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_{ij} v_j$. I want to compute the trace of $\phi$, but it is technically and computably difficult to find a basis and express $\phi$ in terms of it. Can I compute $\mathrm{tr}(\phi)$ in terms of the $\lambda_{ij}$ somehow? After all, they (**edit**: *together* with the $v_i$) completely define the morphism $\phi$. I have no idea where to even start, though.

**Edited Version**
Assume that $V\subseteq \mathbb C^d$ is a subvector space generated by $v_1,\ldots,v_n\in \mathbb C^d$. Assume that $\dim(V)<d$. As before, assume that we know $\lambda_{ij}$ with $\phi(v_i)=\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_{ij} v_j$. The matrix $\Lambda=(\lambda_{ij})$ is very sparse, i.e. only about $n$ of the $\lambda_{ij}$ are not equal to zero. A special case which is already very interesting is $\phi(v_i)=v_{\pi(i)}$ for some permutation $\pi\in S_n$. Furthermore, $d$ is much larger than $n$. I would now like a method to compute the trace of $\phi$ that takes only $O(n)$ many steps, using the $v_i$ and the $\lambda_{ij}$ as input. The $v_i$ can be assumed to be black-box, i.e. given $v_i$ and $k\in\{1,\ldots,d\}$, an oracle will give you the coefficient of $v_i$ with respect to the $k$-th standard basis vector.

Comment: There's a slight discrepancy between the title and body of the question. The title appears to allow using the generating set itself, whereas the body asks for computing the trace solely in terms of the $\lambda_{ij}$ -- my answer refers to the version in the body.

Comment: Well, of course I allow *knowledge* of the $v_i$.

Comment: It seems inappropriate (to me) to write "well, of course" in two places as if I could have divined your intentions, when the question rather unambiguously states that you want to compute the trace "in terms of the $\lambda_{ij}$". I don't understand what you mean by "allowing *knowledge* of the $v_i$". To my mind, either you want to compute the trace in terms of the $\lambda_{ij}$, or in terms of both the $\lambda_{ij}$ and the $v_i$; I don't see in what sense computing it in terms of the $\lambda_{ij}$ while "allowing knowledge of the $v_i$" could constitute a third alternative to these two.

Comment: Note that when you compute the trace from a matrix with respect to a basis, you do *not* need to know the basis, only the matrix, so it wasn't an outlandish idea to think that you were wondering whether this might be possible for a generating set; in fact I upvoted the question because I thought it was an interesting idea.

Comment: You are right. My question is vague and not mathematically precise. I am sorry for the brusque comment. Providing the entire context would have been very lengthy, so I decided to give people the essential idea and ask if someone had an idea on how to tackle it. I will give it some thought and see if I can make this more precise without making it too repulsive.

Comment: I made an edit. Again sorry for being so vague, is this better?

Comment: I didn't mind the vagueness so much as I minded the implication that I was responsible for it :-) Yes, it's much clearer now, but now I wonder how you intend to distinguish between approaches that effectively compute a basis and approaches that don't, since solving the problem by computing a basis is already polynomial in $n$, so your time complexity constraint doesn't exclude that option.

Comment: I should have said $O(n)$ many operations.

Comment: I've deleted my trivial answer to the original question so it doesn't make the question looked answered.